# apt-get update fails after installing chrome and some tweaks

Tags: apt, updates

I was trying to `apt-get update`, but it shows an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Before this error occurred, I installed chrome and some tweak app.

Comment: the second last line in that message is telling you that the tualatrix (ubuntu tweak) ppa you added does not contain packages built for your version of ubuntu (xenial 16.04). this means you cannot install it from the ppa as is.

Comment: note that ubuntu tweak is no longer maintained (https://github.com/tualatrix/ubuntu-tweak/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because there are no release for xenial in this repository. You can check it from [this](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) link.